# Kernel. How to get process name and pid that got CPU timeslice

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I want to print `name` and `pid`of every process that got CPU timeslice.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

for individual process you can get this information in:

```
/proc/<pid>/stat
```

14th and 15th field represents the time spend in usermode and kernel mode respectively. 
By using this you can get the time for all the processes running on your system.

Comment: I want to see print with process name at the moment when it gets CPU timeslice. One of my processes hangs sometimes. So I want to see which one exactly executes